# Using a string to define variable with tuples

Tags: python, string, tuples

I apologize if my question seems novice, but I have hit a roadblock when it comes to assigning variables based on a string for tuples in python (2.7).

In the past I have had no issues assigning a variable and using a string to give it a name (eg: `rowId = '%sDays' %workoutMode`). But in a tuple environment, I am having some issues.

I have three different tables I want to pull from a database and apply the same code to them. In this instance I want to pull the data and print it based on the string from the defined list. But I am having a problem assigning variables based on strings.  Here is my code:

```
def workoutCycle():
    catagories = 'Legs', 'Arms', 'Back'
    for catagory in catagories:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('workoutData.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute ('SELECT round(%sDays, 1), round(%sDaysTotal, 1) FROM Profile_%s' %(catagory, catagory, catagory))
        originalData = c.fetchall()
        ('%sDays' %catagory, '%sDaysTotal' %catagory) = tuple(originalData[0])
        print originalData
        print '%sDays' %catagory
        print '%sDaysTotal' %catagory
```

This code returns:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried different modifications and I'm not having luck. Is there a specific format that I am missing for strings/tuples?

**********EDIT**************

It seems like I wasn't very clear with what I was trying to do. Essentially I'm trying to create a loop to replace having to write a code out for each catagory. So for example I want to print the data pertaining to "Arms", this code works:

```
def armCycle():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('workoutData.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute ('SELECT round(ArmsDays, 1), round(ArmsDaysTotal, 1) FROM Profile_Arms')
    #originalData = c.fetchall()
    originalData = c.fetchall()
    (ArmsDays, ArmsDaysTotal) = tuple(originalData[0])
    print originalData
    print ArmsDays
    print ArmsDaysTotal
```

I'm trying to create a code that is a little more dynamic than just creating a function for each catagory. I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way. I apologize, I'm new to programming.

Comment: Please include the full backtrace.  The backtrace almost certainly shows where the syntax error is.

Comment: `rowId = '%sDays' %workoutMode` is assigning `rowId` variable the value of what `'%sDays' %workoutMode` evaluates to, what you're trying to do here is the opposite and not a valid Python syntax. Check `setattr()` if you want to dynamically create variables.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. Why are you trying to define a tuple like that?

Comment: I just posted a further explanation of what I'm trying to do. Thank you @zwer, I'll look at the setattr() and see if there is a way to make that work.

Comment: What's wrong with just printing the `originalData[0][0]`, `originalData[0][1]`, why do you want to turn transient values into named properties?

Comment: My goal would be to have 6 unique variables: LegsDay, LegsTotal, ArmsDay, ArmsTotal, BackDays, BackTotal. Right now I am only printing, but eventually I want to do some math with them, but it looks like maybe I use static variables as @zwer pointed out and create some sort of logic to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create new variables (`ArmsDays`, `ArmsDaysTotal`) that are named on the basis of the variable `category` that contains the value `"Arms"`. The simplest and usual way to do this is not to create individual variables dynamically, but instead use a `dict`.

```
c.execute ('SELECT round(%sDays, 1), round(%sDaysTotal, 1) FROM Profile_%s' %(category, category, category))
originalData = c.fetchall()

my_dynamic_data = {}

my_dynamic_data['%sDays' %category] = originalData[0][0]
my_dynamic_data['%sDaysTotal' %category] = originalData[0][1]
```

The keys of the `dict` are formed on exactly the same principle as the way you construct the column names in the `select` statement. Then, instead of

```
print '%sDays' %category
print '%sDaysTotal' %category
```

do

```
print my_dynamic_data['%sDays' %category]
print my_dynamic_data['%sDaysTotal' %category]
```

You *can* create new variables dynamically in Python, but if you need to ask how, you shouldn't be doing that. You need a *very* good reason not to use a `dict` for this.